# Why does the swedish translation not work on a swedish device, yet the polish version works?

Tags: android, language-translation

I am using `values-se`, just like `values-pl`, and it shows the swedish flag on `strings.xml`. Contrary to `values-pl` the swedish version is not used when language is set to swedish and it falls back to standard english.

What could be the reason for `values-pl` to work when the device is set to polish, yet `values-se` to not work even though the `strings.xml` shows the swedish flag, like in the other case the polish flag?

Answer (score 1):

For Swedish you will need to use `values-sv`and not `se` which is a regional variant I believe.